# Magento 2 - How to get the extension's configuration values in the phtml files?

Tags: template, configuration, magento2

I'm working with Magento 2 - beta.

But cannot find how to get the configuration values in the phtml files.

eg: I want to get my custom modules configuration values in `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: can you give a real life example? what exactly are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: See https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/GoogleAnalytics/view/frontend/templates/ga.phtml and https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/GoogleAnalytics/Helper/Data.php

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can create a function for getting configuration values in your custom module's helper.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can get the configuration values to call this function in any phtml files.

```
$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section/group/field');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the ScopeConfigInterface is available from the abstract helper class! Saved me redefining it.

Comment: How would this work with a default config value? I'm trying to figure out how to get the phone number set in the store config and display it in the header.phtml

Comment: @Dmitry I think you still need to inject `\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` in helper's constructor

Answer (score 7):

Another way is as below

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('group/field/value');
```

Comment: You should never use the object manager for instantiation of a model

Comment: This one here is sooo wrong.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function getConfig($config_path)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $config_path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}

$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getConfig('section/group/field');
```

Answer (score 2):

Correction in Rushvi's answer: its `section/group/field`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('section/group/field');
```

Also if you want to add store filter for example want to display text if save at store configuration level then just add following:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORES;
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue('carriers/freeshipping/extra_info',$storeScope);
```

Secondly for critiques: its v good to include in your block class's constructor via DI. Here is just concept

Comment: Thanks @hassan for this sollution

Comment: Don’t use the object manager.

Comment: oh really, thanks. Do you know what magento use behind the seen when you inject it ?

Answer (score 2):

**In template (phtml) files, I use in the following way:**

```
$config = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form::class);
$configValue = $config->getConfigValue('web/secure/base_url');
```

Comment: Nice way to avoid creating a new helper, or in cases where there is no specific module.

Comment: This is not proper way how to get any values in PHTML. Even this is doable, you should still use block class or view model.