# Magento 2: Get `core_config_data` Values without Creating a new Module

Tags: magento2, theme, core-config-data

Is there a way in Magento 2.0 to  get a config value and display it in the header without creating a custom module?  I am trying to display the phone number from the admin Stores > Configuration under the search on the front-end header.

I figure I will have to add /app/design/frontend///Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml as well as a layout/default.xml. But, I'm nut sure how to call the phone number.

The two main technical barriers I'm facing are

1. How can I fetch a configuration value from `core_config_data` from a theme.  If possible, I don't want to [create a module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84481/magento-2-how-to-get-the-extensions-configuration-values-in-the-phtml-files) to do this. It seems like there should be a standard object for performing this common task.
2. How can I add content to or replace the `html/header.phtml` template.

Note: This is not a duplicate, as the other question asks about creating a custom module and getting it's configuration values. That is NOT my question. I'm asking how to fetch a default Magento configuration value from core_config_data. Nothing to do with a custom module.

Comment: Not a duplicate. Different question. I'm not looking to develop and extension, but rather call a config value that already exists in the core Magento 2.

Comment: @stefandoom I updated/edit the question text to better reflect the intent of PhilipDeatherage's question. PhilipDeatherage -- let me know if I misinterpreted.

Comment: @AlanStorm Yes, that reflects what I'm looking for.

Comment: Ah now I get it. Looking into it, but can't find it that quick.. maybe not possible at all :(

Comment: The thing is that ScopeConfigInterface is used in AbstractBlock, but there is no public method on it which will be put through to the template. As I see it now there can be one module to make this available for everyone, or a PR to the core to make it accessible from now on, or there is a method we haven't discovered yet :)

Comment: I checked with Magento. There is no way to do this out of the box without writing a new module. Unfortunately.