# Magento 2: get store url without store code [SOLVED]

Tags: magento2, phtml, base-url

How to get **Configuration->Web->Base URLs -> Base URL** in multi store magento 2. I have enabled **Add Store Code to Urls**

I have use on phtml page but it return me url with store code and I need only base url without store code:

```
<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>
```

Output of above code is `www.example.com/de` and my requirement is `www.example.com`

This is magento1 code.

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Core_Model_Url::XML_PATH_UNSECURE_URL);
```

I need it in magento 2.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84481/magento-2-how-to-get-the-extensions-configuration-values-in-the-phtml-files this will help u. & use `web/unsecure/base_url`

Comment: @AnkitShah thanks your for your help. Your link help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found solution. Bellow is my code.

```
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$conf = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface')->getValue("web/unsecure/base_url");?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This works, but please don't use the ObjectManager. Inject the class `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface` into the constructor, assign it to a class variable and use it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK);
```

Comment: i have check your solution but it still give result **www.example.com/de**.

Comment: thanks for help. now i found solution.I have added my solution in answer

Comment: In my case I used this one $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB)